# How to install Graphlab Create on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, proxy, terminal, graphlab

When i am trying to install Graphlab Create, it's just retrying connections. I have healthy broadband wifi connection at my home (NO proxy).

Error: `(graphlab)ankit@ankit21:~$ pip install graphlab-create==0.9.1
Collecting graphlab-create==0.9.1
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd6a16ae850>, 'Connection to 192.168.16.253 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/graphlab-create/`

The proxy 192.168.16.253 is proxy of my college internet. But i have changed the setting in networks setting to automatic proxy. Others installs in terminal are working properly only this is having the problem.

Comment: I can guess it was not problem with proxy, rather with dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need your specific academic license key, but trying to install the older version automatically updates your install to 1.7.1. If you choose to copy your code from the installation instructions and you remove --upgrade, and change to 0.9.1 it will still not work.

```
pip install --no-cache-dir https://get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/0.9.1/your_key/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

You can obtain your key for the latest version when you register with GraphLab on the Dato website. The academic license is free for each user for one year.

Answer (score 0):

On the official site (`https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create.html?email=**YOU**%40gmail.com&key=**7C68-...-D3D7**`) we have:

Registered email address: **YOUR_ADDRESS**

Product key: **YOUR_PRODUCT_KEY**

Installing with dependencies:

- Install Anaconda

  bash /path to download file/Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
- Create conda environment

  conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
  source activate gl-env
- Ensure pip version >= 7

  conda update pip
- Install GraphLab Create

  pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/**YOUR_ADDRESS**/**YOUR_PRODUCT_KEY**/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
- Ensure installation of IPython and IPython Notebook

  conda install ipython-notebook